# gulp & bourbon @include font-face issue - Custom fonts not importing?

Tags: gulp, font-face, bourbon, gulp-sass

I am using gulp for the first time I have everything working how I would like it but an stuck on one issue. I have a custom font family in a fonts folder something like "assets/fonts/font-family/...."

The issue I am having is that normally in a static project I would normally just use bourbon's :

```
@include font-face("source-sans-pro", "/fonts/source-sans-pro/source-sans-pro-regular", $file-formats: eot woff2 woff);
```

This would then allow me to use the family in a regular font-family declaration easy peasy.

However this does not work in my current gulp project. here is the gulpfile I currently have:

```js
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var prefix      = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var cp          = require('child_process');

var messages = {
    jekyllBuild: '<span style="color: grey">Running:</span> $ jekyll build'
};

/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn('jekyll', ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

/**
 * Rebuild Jekyll & do page reload
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll-build'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

/**
 * Wait for jekyll-build, then launch the Server
 */
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass', 'jekyll-build'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: '_site'
        },
        notify: false
    });
});

/**
 * Compile files from _scss into both _site/css (for live injecting) and site (for future jekyll builds)
 */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('assets/css/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['css'],
            onError: browserSync.notify
        }))
        .pipe(prefix(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
});

/**
 * Watch scss files for changes & recompile
 * Watch html/md files, run jekyll & reload BrowserSync
 */
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('assets/css/**', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['index.html', '_layouts/*.html', '_includes/*.html'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
});

/**
 * Default task, running just `gulp` will compile the sass,
 * compile the jekyll site, launch BrowserSync & watch files.
 */
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

I am severely confused as to what I need to do next to get custom assets working for the bourbon include. Maybe this is because I installed bourbon in a normal fashion and gulp isn't handling bourbon? Any direction or critiques are much appreciated.

Comment: It appears that assets/css/ is being added to my font's resource path creating something like: assets/css/assets/fonts/font-family/font family type files. I am wondering what I need to do to create the right file path when my site is compiled? I also assume this will also be an issue for or static resources like images in an images folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of gulp-sass are you using?

I had the same error on version 0.7.3, but upgrading to the current (2.0.4) version fixed this problem.